# Accessing Safari Web Inspector backend server from Swift / WkWebView

Tags: swift, wkwebview, web-inspector, safari-web-inspector

Using Safari's Web Inspector, it's possible to inspect and debug websites remotely.

> The Web Inspector is a multi-tier application. It’s divided into 3 layers: a frontend, a backend and a target.

—from [Architecture of the Web Inspector](http://blogs.igalia.com/dpino/2015/11/22/Architecture-of-the-Web-Inspector/)

In other words, the WkWebView runs a server that can provide Web Inspector information as raw data. The Web Inspector UI is a JavaScript application that works with this raw data.

I can enable the Web Inspector inside a WkWebView using `developerExtrasEnabled` but what I want to do is slightly different. I want to access the backend server from Swift. I want my Swift code to get access to the same raw data that the Web Inpector UI front-end works with.

Is it possible, and if so, can anyone point me in the direction of how?

And where is the data protocol documented?

Comment: The Google Chrome equivalent is documented at http://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/ and you can sniff the web socket traffic between the Devtools front-end and the server as outlined at https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol#sniffing-the%20protocol — this is pretty similar to what I'm hoping to be able to do between Swift and a WKWebView.

Answer (score 1):

I spoke with a member of Apple's webkit team who told me this currently isn't possible — there's no public API implemented that provides access to this data. I've put in a radar issue describing this feature request.